# AutoMapper - Trying to pass variables from WEB API Controller to Automapper configuration at runtime

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper, repository-pattern, dto

I am working on a large project that uses AutoMapper to map entities to DTO's - this works perfectly for simple mappings but I've come unstuck at the moment trying to get some custom mappings to work.

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do. I have a Product, Price and Store class:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public Guid StoreId { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
}
```

Each class also has a DTO. When I access a ProductDTO class by default I will get all prices for all stores. However, when a particular store logs in to the application I want to limit the prices they see to their store only.

I would like AutoMapper to be able to handle this so that when my WEB API Controller calls into the Repository to get a ProductDTO, the list of Prices are automatically filtered to include ONLY the currently logged in stores' prices.

I have set up my AutoMapper configuration in the Startup class of my WEB API project. I know I could set up a custom mapping like so:

```
Mapper.Configuration.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
    .ForMember(pd => pd.Prices,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Prices.Where(pp => pp.StoreId == storeId));
```

but I only know what the currently logged in store ( the storeId ) is once the request comes into the WEB API Controller. So, is it possible to set up my configuration in a way that I can update the configuration during runtime or is there a better way of tackling this altogether ? This is a very simple example - there are hundreds of similar scenarios in this project I am working on ( not limited to filtering by Store ID ) so I would like to implement something as generic as possible.

Comment: why don't you pull the prices of only the logged in user and only those prices will be mapped ? why you want to do filtering of data in automapper.

Comment: This is what I am doing currently but every time I want to get a ProductDto with prices I have to include `Prices.Where(pr => pr.StoreId == storeId)` in the LINQ statement. I was hoping to just hand this off the AutoMapper so this was done each time automatically.

Comment: I think the way to do this is filtering in the query. But you might try an [after action](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions).

Comment: i think doing filtering in automapper mapping is not the best solution , if you want to use try using custom converters or After Action.

Comment: Are you using the LINQ projection from AutoMapper or Mapper.Map?

Comment: @JimmyBogard I am using LINQ Projection from AutoMapper..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [parameterized LINQ query support](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#parameterization) in AutoMapper:

```
int storeId = 0;
Mapper.Configuration.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
    .ForMember(pd => pd.Prices,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Prices.Where(pp => pp.StoreId == storeId));
```

Then in your controller:

```
dbContext.Products.ProjectTo<ProductDto>(new { storeId = currentLoggedInStoreId });
```

AutoMapper will pass that parameter based on it matching "storeId" to your "Where" expression's variable at runtime.